# Timestamp Google Script triggered by formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I am using this Google script to get a timestamp in a column of my Google Sheet once a cell in a set column is updated:

```
function activeSheetName() {
return
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+9";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Profit";
  var timeStampColName = "Time";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName(activeSheetName()); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

The script works when I manually change values in the trigger column. However, I am using a "trigger"-based formula in the trigger column that will auto-update the trigger column as it changes/updates. The problem is that this script will not respond to the triggered data being populated in the column, only manually entered values. How can I get around this?

Comment: Triggers only respond to user actions, or time intervals. They do not fire in response to other trigger outputs. This is clearly described in documentation, and will not change.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your code so that writing the timestamp is accomplished by a stand-alone function. Then have that function be called both by `onEdit()` as well as by your other trigger.

```
function addTimestamp(range) {
  // add the timestamp
}

function onEdit(event) {
  // does something
  addTimestamp(range);
}

function yourOtherTrigger() {
  // does something
  addTimestamp(range);
}
```

You should also review the [event object documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). Your use of `event` is not efficient (especially things like `event.source.getSheetByName(activeSheetName())` and `event.source.getActiveRange()`).

Comment: This seems to make sense, but I'm honestly not good at coding beyond HTML. How could this be implemented into my existing code? Or rather, how would you modify it with your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Formulas can't activate simple or installable triggers. To get around this you have to rethink your solution,

Perhaps instead of "reading" changes cell by cell, read changes made by editing multiple-cells ranges like when the user paste data or do a filldown.

Or maybe you should design a way to capture both the data to be entered and the timestamp.

For some use cases, the easiest solution is to use Google Forms for other you should create a web app.

Reference

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Related

- [onEdit script not firing on Google Sheet in formula based cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46561965/1595451)
- [Formula-based cell changes in Google Sheets is not firing onEdit script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39283234/1595451)